# How to calculate difference between two datetime fields (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss) in time format (hh:mm:ss) in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, datediff, dateadd, datepart

I have 2 columns in my table in sql server – [Occurrence Time (NT)] and [Clearance Time(NT)] having the format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss and a third column [Outage Duration] with the format hh:mm:ss

[Identifier] | [Occurrence Time(NT)] | [Clearance Time(NT)] | [Outage Duration]

4 | 2014-12-28 15:06:33.000 | 2014-12-28 15:18:18.000 | 00:11:45.000

Outage duration is calculated as the difference of [Occurrence Time (NT)] and [Clearance Time(NT)]
Currently my code to do this is as follows :

```
 select distinct  a.[Identifier]
     ,a.[Occurrence Time(NT)]
     ,a.[Clearance Time(NT)]
     ,cast((cast(a.[Clearance Time(NT)] as datetime) - cast(a.[Occurrence Time(NT)]as datetime)) as   time ) 
     as [Outage Duration] 
     from final_report_2   a
```

The cast is just a failsafe as both the columns are already datetime. This code works for all cases where [Occurrence Time (NT)] and [Clearance Time(NT)] fall on the same day i.e. the outage is within 24 hours

For e.g in above row no. 4 both have 28th as the day and thus the outage is calculated correctly.

But the outage duration is wrongly calculated in case of different days.

2678 | 2014-12-28 12:50:04.000 | 2014-12-31 23:59:59.000 | 11:09:55.000

In row 2678 the time should be 83:09:55 instead of 11:09:55.

So I need to factor in the difference of the days as well and then calculate the [Outage duration] in hh:mm:ss format.

One of the possible ways to do this is as follows :

(23:59:59 – 12:50:04) + 00:00:01 + ((31-28-1)*24):00:00 + 23:59:59

where the first part calculates the time of the first day , then the second part calculates the no. of whole days in between the [Occurrence Time (NT)] and [Clearance Time(NT)] and multiplies it by 24 and the final part represents the time of the final day.

How can I implement the above in sql server ? Can it be done using DATEPART or DATEADD functions?

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `datediff` function.

First find the `difference` in `seconds` between the two dates.

```
select Datediff(SECOND, [Clearance Time(NT)], [Occurrence Time(NT)])
```

Now convert the `seconds` to `hh:mm:ss` using this code.

```
DECLARE @TimeinSecond INT
SET @TimeinSecond = 86399 -- Change the seconds
SELECT RIGHT('0' + CAST(@TimeinSecond / 3600 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
RIGHT('0' + CAST((@TimeinSecond / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)  + ':' +
RIGHT('0' + CAST(@TimeinSecond % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)
```

Change your query something like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.[Identifier],
                a.[Occurrence Time(NT)],
                a.[Clearance Time(NT)],
                RIGHT('0' + Cast(Datediff(SECOND, [Clearance Time(NT)],[Occurrence Time(NT)]) / 3600 AS VARCHAR), 2)
                + ':'
                + RIGHT('0' + Cast((Datediff(SECOND, [Clearance Time(NT)],[Occurrence Time(NT)]) / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR), 2)
                + ':'
                + RIGHT('0' + Cast(Datediff(SECOND, [Clearance Time(NT)],[Occurrence Time(NT)]) % 60 AS VARCHAR), 2) [Outage Duration]
FROM   final_report_2 a
```

**Reference:** conversion of `seconds` to `hh:mm:ss` referred from this **[link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/08/17/sql-server-convert-seconds-to-hour-minute-seconds-format/)**

Answer (score 0):

Good old SQL DATEDIFF.
Here's the duration function I use. All wrapped up in a UDF.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fDuration(@DtStart  DATETIME, @DtEnd DATETIME)
RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (
SELECT
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t.Hours) + ':' +
RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t.Minutes), 2) + ':' +
RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t.Seconds - (t.Hours * 60 * 60) - (t.Minutes) * 60), 2) as Value
FROM (
    SELECT 
    t.Hours, 
    ABS(t.Seconds / 60 - (t.Hours * 60)) as Minutes,
    t.Seconds
    FROM (
        SELECT
            DATEDIFF(SECOND, @DtStart, @DtEnd) as Seconds,
            DATEDIFF(SECOND, @DtStart, @DtEnd)/60/60 AS Hours) t
    ) t)
END
```

USAGE:

```
SELECT dbo.fDuration('2014-12-28 12:50:04.000', '2014-12-31 23:59:59.000')
```

RETURNS :

```
83:09:55
```

In your case, you can modify your query like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.[Identifier],
                a.[Occurrence Time(NT)],
                a.[Clearance Time(NT)],
                dbo.fDuration(a.[Occurrence Time(NT)], a.[Clearance Time(NT)]) as [Outage Duration]
FROM   final_report_2 a
```

Or even add [Outage Duration] as a Computed field in final_report_2 with formula

```
dbo.fDuration([Occurrence Time(NT)],[Clearance Time(NT)])
```

Then it becomes a simple select...

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.[Identifier],
                a.[Occurrence Time(NT)],
                a.[Clearance Time(NT)],
                a.[Outage Duration]
FROM   final_report_2 a
```

Note
Hours are not prefixed with a '0'. This allows for negative durations.

Hope that helps